# Installing FreeNAS 9.10.2 on Dell PowerEdge R710

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, truenas

I am currently trying to install FreeNAS 9.10.2 on Dell PowerEdge R710.

I am running FreeNAS off a usb which is loading fine.

I select FreeNAS in the GRUB menu by hitting enter. Once I am in the FreeNAS console setup screen, my keyboard does not work anymore. It is a usb keyboard and I don't have a PS/2 port to use as an alternative.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this has to do with how USB is configured in the BIOS/UEFI. Make sure to enable legacy USB devices, or USB 1.1 emulation. This will make the firmware handle the keyboard, rather than passing control to your OS - and FreeNAS might not work with some of the more "exotic" keyboards unless the firmware is handling that I/O for it. Finally, if that doesn't work, try a different (simpler) USB keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It actually happened to me too, but on different machine (PE2900 III). So I would try to check the iso hash count and burn the image on DVD and use usb DVD drive to install the OS- worked for me. I also have used USB keyboard.

Comment: The Dell Power Edge does have a SATA CD drive included but I ran into the same problem when trying to install FreeNAS via a CD.